# Spring Kafka is Acknowledgement.acknowledge thread safe?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am implementing an kafka based application where I would like to manually acknowledge incoming messages. Architecture forces me to do it in a separate thread.

**The question is: is it possible and safe to execute Acknowledgement.acknowledge() in a different thread than consumer?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, as long as you use `MANUAL` and not `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE`, but I don't think you'll get what you expect.

Kafka doesn't track each message, just offsets within the partition.

Let's say message 1 arrives and you hand off to another thread. Then message 2 arrives and it is handed off to yet another thread.

When the offset for message 2 is ack'd, you are effectively acking both messages.

Comment: Thank you Gary, my scenario is that there will be only one additional thread which will be handling results so it is completely fine.

Comment: `Acknowledgement.acknowledge` makes a call of method `addOffset` in `MANUAL` ack-mode. This method interacts with HashMap field `offsets`: checks key existence, puts value into it. How could it be thread safe?

Comment: Oops; you are correct; [will fix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/566). Contributions welcome. (But it's still unusual to hand off the ack to another thread for the reasons I cited).