# Kafka Acknowledgement.acknowledge() only the offset a Listener finished processing

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

We are developing a SpringBoot application where messages are produced into a Kafka queue, and are pulled by Listeners (across multiple servers, multiple threads can be processing on each server).

When message is processed successfully, we would like to do something like `Acknowledgement.acknowledge()` in the Listener, to mark the message as processed.

However, according to documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/support/Acknowledgment.html:

> Calling this method implies that all the previous messages in the partition have been processed already

I can see this causing a problem with multi threads and race conditions...

Similar unanswered question: 
[Spring Kafka is Acknowledgement.acknowledge thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47652651/spring-kafka-is-acknowledgement-acknowledge-thread-safe)

So, I guess I am asking if `Acknowledgement.acknowledge()` is not the right way to do it, what is? There has to be a way to mark specific message (not the whole offset) as processed...

Thanks!

Comment: We don't mark particular messages, we commit offset in Kafka. So, if you commits, let's say 10, therefore all other offsets `<= 9` are treated as processed as well.

Comment: Which might cause a race condition if 10 was processed before 9, which happened to fail and needs to be reprocessed for example or something else

Comment: You should not use multiple threads for exactly this reason - use concurrency in the container instead - each thread will be assigned different partitions. With kafka messages aren't acknowledged individually; only an offset in the partition is maintained.

Comment: Right, that’s why Kafka recommendation to always process one partition in one thread

Comment: BTW, there is a big difference between an "unanswered" question and one that was answered but not accepted - not everyone understands the Stack Overflow protocol.

Comment: you can also consume one max one messages from kafka and submit ack for it